# Objective-C SpriteKit bodies with different gravities

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, gravity

After much trawling online (SO & lots of others) I give up!

I'm trying to create multiple sprites, each of which is influenced by a different gravity field, but which can still interact with each other. So for instance, one sprite might be attracted to the left of the screen, another to the right, another to the top, etc.

I thought it would be straight-forward, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us your code, por favor.

Comment: I think you can achieve that using applyForce on each body. Since applyForce is applied only for a single simmulation step, you should use it in didSimulatePhysics method in your scene.

Comment: applyForce will need to be applied in the -update: method as it is called before the physics are simulated.

Comment: Thanks guys - I'll try this approach & report back with my results

Comment: I ended up using appyForce & applyImpulse - bit more fiddly than I'd wanted as it meant enumerating through all sprites, but it works fine - thanks